# Magento2 Knockout js - issue on cart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, knockoutjs

I tried to reposition my cart block to a other header location. 
Since then I am getting this javascript error which is annoying since I only repositioned a block.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return { data:cart().items,as:'item'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"
Message: Cannot read property 'simple' of undefined
```

This is the block i repositioned.

```
  <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="store_language" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

Comment: How do you have repositioned this block? Can you specify it in your question?

Comment: Hi there, check the answers & give feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answer [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Can-Magento-do/Magento-2-Mini-Cart-is-not-working-when-changing-the-cart/td-p/29765/#lineardisplaymessageviewwrapper_3) fixed the issue for me

> Minicart is contained by this "header-wrapper". So if you re-declare it in your theme, it causes error. You just need to call it.

We had extended that layout file **app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**, with the intention to add a **CMS block** in header

So instead of *redefining* container

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
        ...
```

Just changing to *referencing* it fixed the issue

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_advice">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_advice</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your custom theme and define it in defalut.xml layout file

**app/design/frontend/vendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

define your container add it before where you want to place minicart then add code as below change element name change template file if required as below

[image]